# Opening a Folder of Files

Tags: macos, finder, folders

If I have a folder full of similar files, is there a technique to open all of its files with a particular app? For example, I would like to right-click on a folder and `Open With` a selected app.

I know I can do this by entering into the folder and selecting some or all of its files. I just wondered whether there is a way to do this on the folder itself.

Comment: Are you looking for an option within the GUI (i.e. the Finder)? Or would an option using Terminal suffice?

Comment: @Monomeeth preferably within Finder. Possibly a Terminal solution can be adapted some how.